# Mount VHDX within WSL Ubuntu 18.04 to edit Linux files

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm looking to change a process (which currently is an elevated PowerShell script running in Windows 10, and I want to keep it close to that) I have that currently uses Paragon Linux Filesystem for Windows tool. While it does work, it doesn't work consistently.  What I'd like to do instead is to use WSL on Windows 10, 1909 currently (will go to 2004 when available), to mount a VHDX which contains to partitions, /dev/sda1 for /boot, and /dev/sda2 another for an Linux LVM.  The OS within this VHDX is CentOS 7.5, and the filesystem I want to modify is formatted in ext4.  I need to edit some files within a logical volume within the group.

Currently, I'm running into an issue where qemu-nbd doesn't help, as there doesn't appear to be an NBD kernel mode driver provided by the Microsoft Linux kernel in Ubuntu 18.04 image from the Windows Store.  I've tried guestfish (using guestmount), but it is unable to find an operating system and fails to mount any of the volumes.

Is this possible?  Am I going down the wrong path, and is this not possible?

Comment: I didn't tried, but you can take a look at:
[mount vhdx in linux](https://gist.github.com/allenyllee/0a4c02952bf695470860b27369bbb60d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSL 2.0 now adds the ability to mount a VHD file, in raw format, using [`wsl --mount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk).  In may case, I needed to mount a VHD file that contains a custom logical volume configuration, and not using the standard ext3/ext4 filesystem.  Using `wsl --mount <path/to/vhd> --vhd --bare`, this has helped me mount my VHDX file.  Then, within the guest OS, I run the following to activate the logical group, and logical volume:

```bash
# FILENAME = ~/config-appliance.sh

mnt=/mnt/lv-root

# find volume groups
sudo vgscan

# find logical volumes
sudo lvscan

# activate the specific logical volume
sudo lvchange -a y /dev/vg01/lv_root

# ensure volume groups are mapped to a device within the system
sudo dmsetup mknodes

# mount the logical volume needed
sudo mount /dev/mapper/vg01-lv_root $mnt

# ADDITIONAL CODE EXECUTED HERE

# unmount the volume
sudo umount $mnt

# diactivate the logical voloume before unmounting the VHD file externally
sudo lvchange -a n /dev/vg01/lv_root
```

I invoke the bash code above by calling `wsl ~/config.sh`, which also performs a number of other processes to modify files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question...
Seems to me that you want to offline access a .vhdx containing Linux
using powershell to manipulate some files...
(I think the issue here is ext4 and file rights)

```
1. Mount the .vhdx you want to '''work''' in a linux virtual machine as second disk
2. Install Powershell 7 in linux VM
3. Configure Powershell remote in the Linux VM (via SSH)
4. Access the Linux VM from Windows Powershell 7 and execute your scripts.
```

> there are other ways using VMs+NBD
>  or using WSL and mounted
> drives...
>  but this seems to be the most practical end efficient!

- as you for sure know you can start/stop the VMs from Powershell